# Battery icon is not displayed on the gnome shell 3 desktop. Running Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, 13.04, battery

This is what I get when I run "gnome-power-statistics"

```
(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:19:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:27:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:40:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:51:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:60:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:70:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:78:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:103:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:116:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:128:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:139:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:216:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:224:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:243:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:253:18: not a number

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:38:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:44:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:54:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:59:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:64:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:68:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:75:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:80:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:85:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:89:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:95:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:100:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:105:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:111:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:121:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:126:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:132:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:136:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:142:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:147:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:152:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:156:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:161:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:166:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:260:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:264:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:269:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:274:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:279:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:284:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:288:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:292:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:297:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:302:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:307:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:312:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:316:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:320:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:325:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:330:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:335:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:340:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:344:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:348:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:353:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:358:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:363:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:368:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:375:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:379:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2395:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2403:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2408:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2413:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2422:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2430:22: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-applications.css:475:25: Not a valid image

(gnome-power-statistics:3305): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-applications.css:491:25: Not a valid image
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
-Lenovo-G580:~$ gnome-power-statisticsgnome-power-statistics
```

The power statistics show that I have a battery on my laptop but the battery/power icon is not displayed which makes it very annoying...

Any help regarding this topic will help!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling these packages

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-power-manager indicator-session
>   pm-utils upower

hope that helps